# Fetch all results in one line csv in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to query

```
select car_name from cars
```

and the expected output is

```
| CAR_NAMES                                 |
|'Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford'| `
```

How can I do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle**

```
SELECT listagg (car_name , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY car_name )
        car_name 
FROM cars
GROUP BY car_name
```

**MySQL**

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(car_name ) AS CAR_NAMES 
FROM cars
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is not available in oracle

Comment: I want the car name within quotes also `'Audi', 'BMW'....`

Comment: @DebajyotiDas - You can try this one. This will give you each of your values in single quotes as you expected

`select listagg(regexp_replace(car_name ,'^|$',''''),',') within group (order by car_name )
from cars
group by car_name;`

Comment: This works `SELECT  listagg( car_name, ', ') within group (order by car_name) car_name from (select '''' || car_name || '''' as car_name from cars)`

Comment: @DebajyotiDas: So finally You got the answer :)